# Implementing different libraries for different Android versions in one project

Tags: android, libraries

I am making an android application, that uses one library for OS versions from 4.0 to 4.2.x and another library for 4.3.x. What is the best way to do it?
Both libraries are in .jar format. My current version of program is working with the first library on android 4.0-4.2.x, I want to add support for 4.3.
Sorry if my questions is not clear, I am a beginner in android development.
Everything must be done in one application, the variant with 2 different apps for different OS versions doesn't suit.
[Link to the article](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=45288378), where the libraries were taken from.

Comment: Just FYI : http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Comment: "that uses one library for os versions from 4.0 to 4.2.x and another libary for 4.3.x" -- why do you believe that this is a good idea? "My current vesrion of program is working with the first library on android 4.0-4.2.x, I want to add support for 4.3" -- what is stopping you from doing that with the existing library? This feels like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/161639).

Comment: this library is not created by myself. the author claims, that it should be used only as written in my question. I just want to know, if there is something like "if android version is 4.3 import this library instead of that one"

Comment: Then why not get rid of the 4.0-4.2 library and use the second library for all versions? Feel free to provide links to the libraries in question.

Comment: Found solution by myself:
I created 2 MainActivities inherited from MainActivity (I've done include library1 in the first one and include library2 in the second one). 
In the MainActivity I've made an if condition, checking the Android version, then I used Intent to open necessary MainActivity for Android version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution by myself: I created 2 MainActivities inherited from MainActivity (I've done include library1 in the first one and include library2 in the second one). In the MainActivity I've made an if condition, checking the Android version, then I used Intent to open necessary MainActivity for Android version.